# Howto fix connection problem while 'connecting Springboot with MySql'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

My application is compiling properly with no errors but there is some connection problem as the table is not getting created in the database

I created an entity model in spring boot framework and used application.properties file to connect with the database

I got the application started but the database is not getting connected

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```